# Taking from the array always at two values

Tags: c#

is it possible that from this array, I always pull out two values in this form:
12,34,56,78,910?

I can get this result right now
[image]

this is my code:

```
  int[] array1 = new int[] { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 };
            for (int i = 0; i < array1.Length; i++)
            {
                try
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(array1[i] + "  " + array1[i+1]);

                }
                catch (System.IndexOutOfRangeException)
                {
                   System.Console.WriteLine(array1[i]);
                    Console.ReadLine();
                }
            }
```

Comment: Don´t catch exceptions you can **avoid** in the first place. You can easily check if your index is greater then the array, don´t rely on an exception.

Answer (score 0):

```
int[] array1 = new int[] { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 };
        for (int i = 0; i < array1.Length; i+=2)
        {
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine(array1[i] + "  " + array1[i+1]);

            }
            catch (System.IndexOutOfRangeException)
            {
               System.Console.WriteLine(array1[i]);
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 int[] array1 = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
        for (int i = 0; i < array1.Length; i++)
        {
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine(array1[i] +""+ array1[i + 1]);i++;

            }
            catch (System.IndexOutOfRangeException)
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine(array1[i]);
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
int[] array1 = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
int i = 0;
while(i < array1.Length-1)
{
    Console.WriteLine(array1[i++]+""+array1[i++]);
}
```